# Sufficient condition for local max

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Consider a function $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a closed and bounded interval. Suppose $f$ is differentiable in $a$. Prove that the condition $f'(a) < 0$ is sufficient to conclude that $f$ reaches a local maximum in $a$.

**Attempt:**
Suppose $f'(a) < 0$. Then we want to show $a$ is a local maximum. Since $f$ is continuous in $a$ (because differentiable) we know that for all $ \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0 $ such that $$ \forall x \in [a, b] : | x - a | < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon. $$ Now let  $x \in [a, b]$ be arbitrary such that $ | x - a | < \delta$. We must then prove that $f(a) \geq f(x)$.

I tried to prove this by contradiction. Suppose that $f(a) < f(x)$ so that $f(x) - f(a) > 0$. Then since $|f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon $ implies that $f(x) - f(a) < \epsilon$, we would have $$ 0 < f(x) - f(a) < \epsilon. $$ I been staring at this inequality, but not sure how to derive a contradiction. Or maybe a direct proof would be a better approach? Help is appreciated.

Comment: $x\in[a,b]$, $x\neq a$ says that $x-a>0$, and if $f(x)-f(a)>0$, then $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}>0$, so $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$ (and we know it exists, since $f$ is differentiable at $a$).

This contradicts the original assumption that $f'(a) < 0$.

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you! You could have posted it as an answer and I'd upvote.

Comment: You're welcome. You had all the required info, but just needed to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in[a,b]$, $x\neq a$ implies that $x−a>0$. If we additionally suppose $f(x)−f(a)>0$, then
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} > 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$$
(And we know the limit exists, since $f$ is differentiable at $a$.) This contradicts the original assumption that $f'(a) < 0$.